# Using 'IEnumerator' to reposition object as soon as it moves outside of camera's field of view)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ienumerator

This code should reposition a `gameObject` as soon as it leaves the camera's field of view. However, the `gameObject` never gets repositioned...

```
IEnumerator Reposition(NinjaStar ninjaStar) {
    bool onScreen = true;
    Renderer renderer = ninjaStar.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer> ();

    yield return new WaitForSeconds (1);

    while (onScreen) {
        if (!renderer.isVisible) {
            ninjaStar.Initiate (0, 0, Vector3.zero); //this code never gets called
            ninjaStar.transform.position = poolPosition; //this code never gets called
            onScreen = false; //this code never gets called
        }
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Renderer.isVisible](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-isVisible.html) Documentation states:

> When running in the editor, the scene view cameras will also cause this value to be true.

So try to build your project to your preferred platform and test it there (for example build for windows and test the .exe).

Alternatively, reposition/rotate your scene view cameras so they dont see the object and test it in the editor.

Comment: thanks a lot you nailed it, however i think it is peculiar that unity would make isVisible work that way...

Comment: Perfect, glad to help. Then you should accept the answer ;)

Comment: Sometimes, you can be stuck with a problem if you don't read the doc.